# Don't style parent element on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm making a comment box which allows for nested comments and is basically structured like this:

```
<article class="comment">
  Level 1 comment
  <article class="comment">
    Level 2 comment
  </article>
  <article class="comment">
    Level 2 comment
    <article class="comment">
      Level 3 comment
    </article>
  </article>
</article>
```

I use `.comment:hover` to highlight the background of the currently hovered element; however, this causes all parent elements to be highlighted, too. This is what I'm trying to avoid.

At the same time, I'd like to keep the nested structure, so that each comment's highlight encloses the hovered comment's children, too.

Comment: Uhhhm why not simply give the lower level `article`s a different class or an extra class which you can style?

Comment: Can you not give each article a different class name?

Comment: How does adding a different class name help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at

```
<article class="comment">
    <span>Level 1 comment</span>
  <article class="comment">
      <span>Level 2 comment</span>
  </article>
  <article class="comment">
    <span>Level 2 comment</span>
    <article class="comment">
      <span>Level 3 comment</span>
    </article>
  </article>
</article>​
```

css

```
article > span:hover
{
    background-color: red;
}​
```

Basically you just need to wrap them into something in order to become singular

http://jsfiddle.net/bYmjf/1 <-- Working example

Answer (score 1):

You may want to experiment with a cross-browser alternative to *pointer-events* as discussed [here](http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/); however I'd still changing the structure of classes applied to your elements instead for easier maintainability.